# SQL query. Should I loop through specific date range?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, datetime, mariadb

I am making a hotel management system. I need your help with appropriate statement to execute. Can you please have a look?

[This is all room_types = 3, their check-in and check-out date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TzIL.png)

If I make query "SELECT * from rooms WHERE room_type = 3 AND check_in_date BETWEEN '2021-02-12' AND '2021-02-13'" this is what it returns

[it returns only one room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9PnX.png)

but BETWEEN '2021-02-12' AND '2021-02-13'" there will 5 rooms with room_type = 3 in house. How can write a query that returns it?

[I need to return these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keTsQ.png)

Because all those 4 rooms with type=3 will be in house BETWEEN '2021-02-12' AND '2021-02-13'

I am using MariaDB with ORACLE syntax.

Thank you!

Comment: "MariaDB with Oracle syntax" makes no sense.  Please clarify.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @GordonLinoff guessing that is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_oracle (which is deprecated, and removed in mysql 8)

Comment: In MariaDB 10.3 and later, setting the sql_mode system variable to Oracle allows the server to understand a subset of Oracle's PL/SQL language. For example:

SET SQL_MODE='ORACLE';

Comment: sorry, misread that as saying mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want a date range overlap:

```
select * 
from rooms 
where room_type = 3 
  and check_in_date  <= '2021-02-13'
  and check_out_date >= '2021-02-12'
```

This brings rooms that have a reservation that overlap the given range.

Comment: Thanks you very much. This is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

From your first screenshot, I see only one room with a checkin date between the 12th and the 13th.  That room is returned in the result in your second screenshot.  To my eye that one row is the expected result for the criteria you specified.

Maybe as GMB suggests, you are looking to consider both the checkin date and the checkout date?

Karl

Comment: But total rooms in specified time period  = 4. I needed a script that returns it. Thank you though GMB solved the issue.